# Product images do not show on Category pages and do show on product view pages

Tags: magento-1.8, product-images

There is a lot written about this kind of issues. but all do not seem to be the same as what we are experiencing.

We have a big portion of products (so not all) that has product images not shown in the category list.phtml but are shown at the view.phtml (product detail page).

## This is what we tried already

- Changed from normal to flat catalogue
- Reindex
- Check to be sure the correct storeview has a default image selected
- Chmod -R 777 Media/Catalog
- Removed image cache to let it regenerate
- Changed the code in the backend from small_image to image
- Removed ->resize(135) to show original image
- Checked error and access log for error or notices related to this
- Removed .htaccess from media folder

Nothing seem to help what to try next?

Comment: May be a stupid question, but you do not state you tried it: what happens if you grab the image url from the image src, and try and load in in browser direct?  If you look in the file system, does the path/file actually exist, and have the right perms? Compared to the url for the image that works in view, what is different in the two url's?

Comment: Have you assign the image for `small, base and thumbnail ` ?

Comment: @ProxiBlue When i do that, i just gives me the placeholder.png url right away.. but the image should exist since the detail page is working fine.

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaramR Yes i did

Comment: 'but the image should exist since the detail page is working fine' - not true - different sized images, thus different cache locations. Did you look on file system if file exists, and is the url path for both the same?

Comment: Yes but as i also stated, that i tried to load the exact same (bigger) image as on the detail page, and that one also turned up with a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate this is a few months old but stumbled across the post whilst trying to search for the answer for my own site (the exact problem I had) and after struggling through a few more complex options a simple 'Flush Catalog Images Cache' within 'System > Cache Management worked to get the images back and working.